# Как запретить переход по ссылке при движении мышкой?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть конструкция с полосой прокрутки, которую можно двигать мышкой, но проблема в том что если зажать мышку передвинуть в сторону и отжать происходит переход по ссылке, как сделать так чтоб этого перехода при движении мышкой не было.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения] Код ниже

```js
const slider = document.querySelector('.scroll');
let isDown = false;
let startX;
let scrollLeft;

slider.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
  isDown = true;
  slider.classList.add('active');
  startX = e.pageX - slider.offsetLeft;
  scrollLeft = slider.scrollLeft;
 
});
slider.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
  isDown = false;
  slider.classList.remove('active');
});
slider.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
  isDown = false;
  slider.classList.remove('active');
  
});
slider.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
  if(!isDown) return;
  e.preventDefault();
  const x = e.pageX - slider.offsetLeft;
  const walk = (x - startX) * 1; //scroll-fast
  slider.scrollLeft = scrollLeft - walk;
  console.log(walk);
});
```

```css
.scroll { position: relative; width: 100%;overflow-x: auto;overflow-y: hidden; user-select: none; cursor: pointer;height: 300px;visibility: hidden; -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;transition: all 0.3s ease;}
.scroll:hover {visibility: visible; -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease; transition: all 0.3s ease;}
.scroll.active { background: rgba(255,255,255,0.3); cursor: grabbing; cursor: -webkit-grabbing;}
.scroll::-webkit-scrollbar {  width: 10px;}
.scroll::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {  border-radius: 10px;  background-color: #18aaaa;}
.scroll::-webkit-scrollbar-track {  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.2); -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);  border-radius: 10px;  background-color: black;
  -o-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);}
  .slider {visibility: visible; position: absolute; display: flex;left: 5px; }
.filmhit {width: 180px;height: 250px;overflow: hidden;border-radius: 25px; display: inline-flex;position: relative;text-align: center;    border: 2px solid black;}
.filmhit a span {position: absolute; z-index: 2;top: 206px; height: 40px;overflow: hidden;width: 100%;display: flex;align-items: center;justify-content: center;}
.filmhit img {width: 100%;height: 100%;position: absolute;}
.filmshadow {opacity: 0; width: 100%;height: 100%;border-radius: 25px; display: block;overflow: hidden;position: absolute;background: rgba(0,0,0,0.53) url(../images/style/slider1_play.png) no-repeat center;
  z-index: 2; line-height: 200px; -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;-o-transition: all 0.5s ease;transition: all 0.5s ease;}
.filmhit:hover .filmshadow {opacity: 1;}

.filmhit a::before {  bottom: 0; content: ""; display: block; position: absolute; z-index: 2; height: 120px; width: 100%; background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.95) 100%);}
```

```html
 <div class="scroll" >
                        
   <div class="slider"> 
    <div class="filmhit">
    

<a href="https://sefil.ru/films/483-forsazh-the-fast-and-the-furious-2001.html" title="Форсаж / The Fast and the Furious (2001)"><div class="filmshadow"></div>
    <img src="https://sefil.ru/uploads/posts/2023-02/1676715691-1717811566-opasnaya-priroda.webp" alt="Фильм Форсаж / The Fast and the Furious (2001) (The Fast and the Furious)  трейлер, актеры, отзывы и другая информация на СеФил.РУ" title="Форсаж / The Fast and the Furious (2001)"  />
    <span>Форсаж / The Fast and the Furious (2001)</span>
</a>
</div>

<div class="filmhit">
    

<a href="https://sefil.ru/films/33-posledniy-bogatyr-koren-zla-2020.html" title="Последний богатырь: Корень зла (2020)"><div class="filmshadow"></div>
    <img src="https://sefil.ru/uploads/posts/2023-02/1676715691-1717811566-opasnaya-priroda.webp" alt="Русский Фильм Последний богатырь: Корень зла (2020)   трейлер, актеры, отзывы и другая информация на СеФил.РУ" title="Последний богатырь: Корень зла (2020)"  />
    <span>Последний богатырь: Корень зла (2020)</span>
</a>
</div>

<div class="filmhit">
    

<a href="https://sefil.ru/films/12-mulan-mulan-2020.html" title="Мулан / Mulan (2020)"><div class="filmshadow"></div>
    <img src="https://sefil.ru/uploads/posts/2023-02/1676715691-1717811566-opasnaya-priroda.webp" alt="Фильм Мулан / Mulan (2020) (Mulan)  трейлер, актеры, отзывы и другая информация на СеФил.РУ" title="Мулан / Mulan (2020)"  />
    <span>Мулан / Mulan (2020)</span>
</a>
</div>

<div class="filmhit">
    

<a href="https://sefil.ru/films/34-posledniy-bogatyr-2017.html" title="Последний богатырь (2017)"><div class="filmshadow"></div>
    <img src="https://sefil.ru/uploads/posts/2023-02/1676715691-1717811566-opasnaya-priroda.webp" alt="Русский Фильм Последний богатырь (2017)   трейлер, актеры, отзывы и другая информация на СеФил.РУ" title="Последний богатырь (2017)"  />
    <span>Последний богатырь (2017)</span>
</a>
</div>

<div class="filmhit">
    

<a href="https://sefil.ru/films/19-prostaya-prosba-a-simple-favor-2018.html" title="Простая просьба (2018)"><div class="filmshadow"></div>
    <img src="https://sefil.ru/uploads/posts/2023-02/1676715691-1717811566-opasnaya-priroda.webp" alt="Фильм Простая просьба (2018) (A Simple Favor)  трейлер, актеры, отзывы и другая информация на СеФил.РУ" title="Простая просьба (2018)"  />
    <span>Простая просьба (2018)</span>
</a>
</div>

<div class="filmhit">
    

<a href="https://sefil.ru/films/18-most-v-terabitiyu-bridge-to-terabithia-2006.html" title="Мост в Терабитию (2006)"><div class="filmshadow"></div>
    <img src="https://sefil.ru/uploads/posts/2023-02/1676715691-1717811566-opasnaya-priroda.webp" alt="Фильм Мост в Терабитию (2006) (Bridge to Terabithia)  трейлер, актеры, отзывы и другая информация на СеФил.РУ" title="Мост в Терабитию (2006)"  />
    <span>Мост в Терабитию (2006)</span>
</a>
</div>

<div class="filmhit">
    

<a href="https://sefil.ru/films/17-misterium-ohotniki-na-fazanov-fasandraeberne-2014.html" title="Мистериум: Охотники на фазанов (2014)"><div class="filmshadow"></div>
    <img src="https://sefil.ru/uploads/posts/2023-02/1676715691-1717811566-opasnaya-priroda.webp" alt="Фильм Мистериум: Охотники на фазанов (2014) (Fasandræberne) смотреть онлайн, а также трейлер, актеры, отзывы и другая информация на СеФил.РУ" title="Мистериум: Охотники на фазанов (2014)"  />
    <span>Мистериум: Охотники на фазанов (2014)</span>
</a>
</div>

<div class="filmhit">
    

<a href="https://sefil.ru/films/16-pipec-kick-ass-2010.html" title="Пипец (2010)"><div class="filmshadow"></div>
    <img src="https://sefil.ru/uploads/posts/2023-02/1676715691-1717811566-opasnaya-priroda.webp" alt="Фильм Пипец (2010) (Kick-Ass) смотреть онлайн, а также трейлер, актеры, отзывы и другая информация на СеФил.РУ" title="Пипец (2010)"  />
    <span>Пипец (2010)</span>
</a>
</div>

<div class="filmhit">
    

<a href="https://sefil.ru/films/15-pulya-bullet-2013.html" title="Пуля (2013)"><div class="filmshadow"></div>
    <img src="https://sefil.ru/uploads/posts/2023-02/1676715691-1717811566-opasnaya-priroda.webp" alt="Фильм Пуля (2013) (Bullet) смотреть онлайн, а также трейлер, актеры, отзывы и другая информация на СеФил.РУ" title="Пуля (2013)"  />
    <span>Пуля (2013)</span>
</a>
</div>

<div class="filmhit">
    

<a href="https://sefil.ru/films/13-11-intouchables-2011.html" title="1+1 (2011)"><div class="filmshadow"></div>
    <img src="https://sefil.ru/uploads/posts/2023-02/1676715691-1717811566-opasnaya-priroda.webp" alt="Фильм 1+1 (2011) (Intouchables)  трейлер, актеры, отзывы и другая информация на СеФил.РУ" title="1+1 (2011)"  />
    <span>1+1 (2011)</span>
</a>
</div>                        
                                
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: видимо нужен код, в котором видно будет все косяки

Comment: Код добавил, правда, на самом сайте выглядит по другому.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно блокировать ссылки, пока происходит свайп. Примерно вот так это можно сделать:

```js
const slider = document.querySelector('.scroll');
let isDown = false;
let isMove = false; // Переменная, отвечающаяя за состояние свайпа
let startX;
let scrollLeft;

slider.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
  isDown = true;
  slider.classList.add('active');
  startX = e.pageX - slider.offsetLeft;
  scrollLeft = slider.scrollLeft;
});

slider.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
  isDown = false;
  slider.classList.remove('active');
});

slider.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
  isDown = false;

  /*
    Если отжали ЛКМ, то свайп закончен.
    Но не сразу, чтобы не стриггерить клик в момент, когда переменная станет false
  */
  setTimeout(() => {
    isMove = false;
  }, 50);
  slider.classList.remove('active');

});
slider.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
  if (!isDown) return;
  isMove = true; // Меняем переменную
  e.preventDefault();
  const x = e.pageX - slider.offsetLeft;
  const walk = (x - startX) * 1; //scroll-fast
  slider.scrollLeft = scrollLeft - walk;
  // console.log(walk);
});

/*
  Блокируем все ссылки, если свайпаем
*/
const links = document.querySelectorAll('.slider a');
links.forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    if (isMove) e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```css
.scroll {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 300px;
  visibility: hidden;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.scroll:hover {
  visibility: visible;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.scroll.active {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  cursor: grabbing;
  cursor: -webkit-grabbing;
}

.scroll::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
}

.scroll::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #18aaaa;
}

.scroll::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: black;
  -o-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.slider {
  visibility: visible;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  left: 5px;
}

.filmhit {
  width: 180px;
  height: 250px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 25px;
  display: inline-flex;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.filmhit a span {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 206px;
  height: 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.filmhit img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}

.filmshadow {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 25px;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.53) url(../images/style/slider1_play.png) no-repeat center;
  z-index: 2;
  line-height: 200px;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.filmhit:hover .filmshadow {
  opacity: 1;
}

.filmhit a::before {
  bottom: 0;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  height: 120px;
  width: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.95) 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll">

  <div class="slider">
    <div class="filmhit">


      <a href="https://sefil.ru/films/483-forsazh-the-fast-and-the-furious-2001.html" title="Форсаж / The Fast and the Furious (2001)">
        <div class="filmshadow"></div>
        <img src="https://sefil.ru/uploads/posts/2023-02/1676715691-1717811566-opasnaya-priroda.webp" alt="Фильм Форсаж / The Fast and the Furious (2001) (The Fast and the Furious)  трейлер, актеры, отзывы и другая информация на СеФил.РУ" title="Форсаж / The Fast and the Furious (2001)"
        />
        <span>Форсаж / The Fast and the Furious (2001)</span>
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="filmhit">


      <a href="https://sefil.ru/films/33-posledniy-bogatyr-koren-zla-2020.html" title="Последний богатырь: Корень зла (2020)">
        <div class="filmshadow"></div>
        <img src="https://sefil.ru/uploads/posts/2023-02/1676715691-1717811566-opasnaya-priroda.webp" alt="Русский Фильм Последний богатырь: Корень зла (2020)   трейлер, актеры, отзывы и другая информация на СеФил.РУ" title="Последний богатырь: Корень зла (2020)"
        />
        <span>Последний богатырь: Корень зла (2020)</span>
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="filmhit">


      <a href="https://sefil.ru/films/12-mulan-mulan-2020.html" title="Мулан / Mulan (2020)">
        <div class="filmshadow"></div>
        <img src="https://sefil.ru/uploads/posts/2023-02/1676715691-1717811566-opasnaya-priroda.webp" alt="Фильм Мулан / Mulan (2020) (Mulan)  трейлер, актеры, отзывы и другая информация на СеФил.РУ" title="Мулан / Mulan (2020)" />
        <span>Мулан / Mulan (2020)</span>
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="filmhit">


      <a href="https://sefil.ru/films/34-posledniy-bogatyr-2017.html" title="Последний богатырь (2017)">
        <div class="filmshadow"></div>
        <img src="https://sefil.ru/uploads/posts/2023-02/1676715691-1717811566-opasnaya-priroda.webp" alt="Русский Фильм Последний богатырь (2017)   трейлер, актеры, отзывы и другая информация на СеФил.РУ" title="Последний богатырь (2017)" />
        <span>Последний богатырь (2017)</span>
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="filmhit">


      <a href="https://sefil.ru/films/19-prostaya-prosba-a-simple-favor-2018.html" title="Простая просьба (2018)">
        <div class="filmshadow"></div>
        <img src="https://sefil.ru/uploads/posts/2023-02/1676715691-1717811566-opasnaya-priroda.webp" alt="Фильм Простая просьба (2018) (A Simple Favor)  трейлер, актеры, отзывы и другая информация на СеФил.РУ" title="Простая просьба (2018)" />
        <span>Простая просьба (2018)</span>
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="filmhit">


      <a href="https://sefil.ru/films/18-most-v-terabitiyu-bridge-to-terabithia-2006.html" title="Мост в Терабитию (2006)">
        <div class="filmshadow"></div>
        <img src="https://sefil.ru/uploads/posts/2023-02/1676715691-1717811566-opasnaya-priroda.webp" alt="Фильм Мост в Терабитию (2006) (Bridge to Terabithia)  трейлер, актеры, отзывы и другая информация на СеФил.РУ" title="Мост в Терабитию (2006)" />
        <span>Мост в Терабитию (2006)</span>
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="filmhit">


      <a href="https://sefil.ru/films/17-misterium-ohotniki-na-fazanov-fasandraeberne-2014.html" title="Мистериум: Охотники на фазанов (2014)">
        <div class="filmshadow"></div>
        <img src="https://sefil.ru/uploads/posts/2023-02/1676715691-1717811566-opasnaya-priroda.webp" alt="Фильм Мистериум: Охотники на фазанов (2014) (Fasandræberne) смотреть онлайн, а также трейлер, актеры, отзывы и другая информация на СеФил.РУ" title="Мистериум: Охотники на фазанов (2014)"
        />
        <span>Мистериум: Охотники на фазанов (2014)</span>
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="filmhit">


      <a href="https://sefil.ru/films/16-pipec-kick-ass-2010.html" title="Пипец (2010)">
        <div class="filmshadow"></div>
        <img src="https://sefil.ru/uploads/posts/2023-02/1676715691-1717811566-opasnaya-priroda.webp" alt="Фильм Пипец (2010) (Kick-Ass) смотреть онлайн, а также трейлер, актеры, отзывы и другая информация на СеФил.РУ" title="Пипец (2010)" />
        <span>Пипец (2010)</span>
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="filmhit">


      <a href="https://sefil.ru/films/15-pulya-bullet-2013.html" title="Пуля (2013)">
        <div class="filmshadow"></div>
        <img src="https://sefil.ru/uploads/posts/2023-02/1676715691-1717811566-opasnaya-priroda.webp" alt="Фильм Пуля (2013) (Bullet) смотреть онлайн, а также трейлер, актеры, отзывы и другая информация на СеФил.РУ" title="Пуля (2013)" />
        <span>Пуля (2013)</span>
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="filmhit">


      <a href="https://sefil.ru/films/13-11-intouchables-2011.html" title="1+1 (2011)">
        <div class="filmshadow"></div>
        <img src="https://sefil.ru/uploads/posts/2023-02/1676715691-1717811566-opasnaya-priroda.webp" alt="Фильм 1+1 (2011) (Intouchables)  трейлер, актеры, отзывы и другая информация на СеФил.РУ" title="1+1 (2011)" />
        <span>1+1 (2011)</span>
      </a>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: А может заодно подскажете как можно реализовать, чтобы работало 2 таких скрулбара, а то 2 делаю верхний работает, нижний нет.

Comment: @Иван `querySelector` найдёт только первый элемент по подходящему селектору и на него навешает ивенты. Поэтому и работает только на первом. `querySelector` надо менять на `querySelectorAll` и по forEach все ивенты вешать на каждый элемент (примерно так же, как и я ссылки обработал).

Comment: А не сложно написать как это сделать, а то кучу вариантов перепробовал. Но немного не понимаю как это работает

Comment: Я вроде сделал, но теперь мышка прилипает и срабатывает автоматически

Comment: Все разобрался, спасибо большое.